# Concatenation of 2 values from same column using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to concatenate the values of a column.

For EX:

```
select case when month=1 then month_name1 
when month =12 then month_name2 END
from Calendar
where month in (1,12)
```

results:

```
Jan
Dec
```

Target results:

```
Jan - Dec
```

tried different ways but couldn't get it. looks very simple but hard luck. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is using PL/SQL an option?

Comment: Not there yet :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use **aggregate function** `max` as following:

```
select max(case when month=1 then month_name1 end)
       || ' - '||
       max(case when month=12 then month_name2 end)
from Calendar
where month in (1,12);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Don't you feel in your logic, you may need to add concatenation operator before 2nd iteration of max function.

Comment: No @SaiprasadBane. Test it and you will know the result.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you would need a hack here, below query must do the magic !!

`select c1.month_name1 || ' - ' || c2.month_name2 
from Calendar c1, calendar c2
where c1.month = 1 and c2.month = 12 ;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query using `listagg`

```
select listagg(case when month=1 then month_name1 
               when month =12 then month_name2 END, ' - ')
         within group (order by month)
from Calendar
where month in (1,12)
```